# Cannot authenticate to Tomcat 8 manager

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I try to login to Tomcat Manager Application, but the login always fails and shows an error 401 Unauthorized.

Tomcat v8.0.30
Debian, Mozilla

The user in $CATALINA_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="admin" 
      password="root" 
      roles="manager-gui,manager-status,manager-script"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, try to add tomcat role:

```
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="admin" 
  password="root" 
  roles="tomcat,manager-gui,manager-status,manager-script"/>
```

Comment: I'm not sure which was the cause but the issue resolved itself. Thnx anyway.